# Simultaneous connection issue with boost SSL connection

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, client-server, boost-asio

Below pseudo code explains the situation I am facing

Server side

```
while (<some condition>)
{
    // wait for SSL connection
    acceptor.async_accept();

    // wait until connection
    io_service.run();

    // perform handshake
    ssl_socket.handhake();

    // handshake successfully complete, start command manager thread
    pthread_create();

    io_service.reset();
    // Go for the new connection waiting
}
```

What the problem here is I am able to connect two clients but not simultaneously.
1 connection arrives after which it takes 40-50 milliseconds for handshake and certificate verification and due to this reason any connection request in between fails.

**Update:**

Is there any way to stop listening client hello while handshaking is in progress?
I have to create new `io_service` instance for each loop as I might want to cancel the specific thread using `io_service.stop()` call. Does boost have any other option for the same?

Comment: while the TCP handshake is done in the OS kernel so that accept() returns with a connected socket, the SSL handshake is done in userspace. This means that inside socket.handshake() the application will wait for the SSL client hello, do some kind of expensive cryptographic operations and then send the SSL server hello. This takes some time and a bad behaving client might make the handshake stall by simply not sending anything after the initial TCP connect.

Comment: thanks @SteffenUllrich, Please suggest a way to overcome this situation if you have any. I am new to boost.

Comment: I don't use boost myself, but SSL handling is not so different between various languages. Maybe it would be in this case as simple as moving the SSL handshake into the newly created thread instead of doing it in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronous `ssl_socket.handshake()` will prevent additional connections from being accepted. Use `ssl_socket.async_handshake()` if you desire asynchronous behavior.

Also worth noting: you won't need a connection per-thread as that design won't scale beyond trivial examples.

Comment: Hi Sam, I tried with `async_handshake` but it didn't help. My design is like that only. 10 connections are possible and with each connection command thread is started.